# Why can't I include underscore in numbers?

Tags: php, numbers, php-7.4

I have seen someone recently write million in the following way:

```
$myNumber = 1_000_000;
```

When I tried to use this in my PHP code I got the error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '_000_000' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in /in/2MYCH on line 3

What is this notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since PHP 7.4 you can use an underscore to separate the digits in a number.
See this RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/numeric_literal_separator

This change has been implemented to make it easier for human eyes to tell how many digits there are in a numeric literal.

For example:

```
usleep(3500000); // Difficult: How many microseconds is this?
usleep(3_500_000); // Easy: This is 3.5 million
```

This notation works with all numeric literal notations supported by PHP, e.g. integers, floats, hexadecimal.

Comment: Not to belittle your _thorough research_, but this new feature is just one of the many interesting new features you can easily find and track on [migration](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php)